# rxtxSerial.dll for MacOS 10.8

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion, zigbee

I'm currently working on a ZigBee project and I'm programming on an Mac with Mountain Lion (10.8) and using Eclipse IDE. To use my Zigbee Module via USB for Serial communication, I need this rxtxSerial.dll. I only have a Windows compatible version right now.

Is somebody able to provide the necessary link to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Edit2

With all the latest updates as of 2012-11-15 (OSX 10.8.2) i needed to install glibtool via homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) before I got the procedure below to work.

With homebrew installed and configured just do

```
brew install libtool
```

from a terminal.
Then proceed as described below.

/Edit2

Edit

So, I managed to compile it for my self on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2) and XCode (free from App Store).

Download [rxtx-2.2pre2.zip](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download) and extract. Edit the "configure" file in the extracted directory and change the line that reads:

```
JAVAINCLUDEDIR=$JPATH/../../../Headers
```

to

```
JAVAINCLUDEDIR=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

Then configure by doing

> ./configure

using a terminal in your working directory.

Now you will have a file named "Makefile" in your working directory, you need to edit the line in this file that reads:

```
LIBTOOLC = $(GLIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(VERBOSE_IOEXCEPTIONS) -c
```

to

```
LIBTOOLC = $(GLIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(VERBOSE_IOEXCEPTIONS) -c
```

And then run

> make

You will now have RXTXcomm.jar in your working directory and librxtxSerial.jnilib in workingdirectory/i386-apple-darwin12.2.0

These are the files you need.

To work with them you may need to do

> sudo mkdir /var/lock
>
> sudo chmod 777 /var/lock

This approach worked for me.

PS. If you trust me you can get these files from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7099879/librxtxSerial.jnilib) and [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7099879/RXTXcomm.jar).

PPS. You may get:

> WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch   Jar version = RXTX-2.2-20081207
>   Cloudhopper Build rxtx.cloudhopper.net    native lib Version =
>   RXTX-2.2pre2

But it should still work.

/Edit

I am also trying to use rxtx on ML and while I have not have any success yet I did find this link.
[Java 6 and librxtxSerial.jnilib on Intel Mac OS X](http://blog.iharder.net/2009/08/18/rxtx-java-6-and-librxtxserial-jnilib-on-intel-mac-os-x/)
And even though it says nothing about ML, one of the comments states that it works with Lion if you tweak it a little bit.

I'll report back if I get it to work here.

Comment: when doing make i get an error: i686-apple-darwin12.2.0/SerialImp.o & i686-apple-darwin12.2.0/fuserImp.o' no such file or directory? any ideas?

Comment: If you have Homebrew installed you can do "brew install libtool" then follow the guide above. This worked for me with all the latest updates from Apple. And without "brew install libtool" I now get the same error as you do.

Comment: you might have to link glibtool to make this work "brew link libtool"

Comment: This worked for me on Mojave, my JAVAINCLUDE was different because of the different version of MacOS.. and I ended up moving all of the header files to the root of the source anyhow to just end the madness, the compiler kept looking for them in the source root anyhow. It may be noted that my end goal was to just have RXTXcomm.jar and librxtxSerial.jnilib (and put them in /Library/Java/Extensions/ ) to run another project.. a repeatable process was not really my goal here.