# Npm not working after Mavericks update

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, npm

My npm in terminal isn't working after Mavericks update.

`node app.js` works well and runs my app, but when I run `npm` followed by anything I get `-bash: npm: command not found`. I know this question has been asked before here:

[Global installation with npm doesn't work after Mac OS X Mavericks update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562041/global-installation-with-npm-doesnt-work-after-mac-os-x-mavericks-update)
and 
[How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm?rq=1)
and [npm not working after reinstalling Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400073/npm-not-working-after-reinstalling-mac-os-x)
, but none of the answers resolved my situation.

`$ echo $PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin`

Comment: Turned out to be something called glibtools.

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/1200 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139765/rxtxserial-dll-for-macos-10-8

Answer (score 0):

How did you install node.js ? typically it comes bundled with both node and npm, where both are in the same directory.  My suggestion is to remove your current install(s) and do the following with just works.

to install nodejs and npm as yourself NOT root do these commands (OSX/linux) :

```
parent_dir=${HOME}/bin_xxxx  #  replace bin_xxx with something specific
                             #  to node release like bin_v0.10.31

mkdir ${parent_dir}
```

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

```
cd node-v0.xxxx

./configure   --prefix=${parent_dir}/nodejs

make -j8
make install
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

```
export PATH=${parent_dir}/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

define environment variable NODE_PATH so node can find dir for modules otherwise
npm install xxx will put newly installed module into dir in curr dir :

```
export NODE_PATH=${parent_dir}/nodejs/lib/node_modules
```

do above AND use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
always use the -g for global so it gets installed into dir $NODE_PATH
and not your $PWD

nodejs install gives you npm as well :

```
ls -la ${parent_dir}/nodejs/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

For Debian, after installing node do following

```
curl -k -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
sh install.sh
```